# Mycurvefit.com for regression not working

Tags: regression, curves

I was testing some non linear Fit, so i entered the website [Mycurvefit](https://www.mycurvefit.com/) and used some sample data:

```
  Y    X   
 ---- ---- 
  10    7  
  20   13  
  30   17  
  40   23
```

And Fitted with a Polynomial Cubic Regression and got this equation:

```
y = -5 + 1.633333*x - 0.05*x^2 + 0.0006666667*x^3
```

And curve: [image: Graph]

But when i make [y = -5 + 1.633333*x - 0.05*x^2 + 0.0006666667*x^3, x=7](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+-5+%2B+1.633333*x+-+0.05*x%5E2+%2B+0.0006666667*x%5E3,+x%3D7) the output is y=4 when x=7.

What am i doing wrong? Or is the website making some fitting regressions wrongly?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You put in the data wrongly, swapping x and y.

Comment: Thank you! I was careless! The right equation is `y = 22.03125 - 4.489583*x + 0.46875*x^2 - 0.01041667*x^3`